# System services not available to Activities before onCreate()?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Currently I'm trying to make a media player, and im trying to call the updateMusic method from an activity class that I created that does that, and show it into a listFragemnt class

but I keep getting this error and im not sure how to make it work
I recently had the entire application formated in Activities and it worked perfectly fine, so im trying to format it to fragments so I can add a viewpager for swiping, but thats besides the point

MediaActivity class

```
 public class MediaActivity extends ListActivity {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/");
    public Uri uriMusic = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/MUSIC/");
    public Uri uriVideo = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/VIDEOS/");
    private static final String SD_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/");
    public static final String MUSIC_PATH = new String("/storage/emulated/0/MUSIC/");
    public static final String VIDEO_PATH = new String("/storage/emulated/0/VIDEOS/");

     public List<String> videos = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
 public void updateMusic() {

        File home = new File(MUSIC_PATH);
        if (home.listFiles(new mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new mp3Filter())) {
                songs.add(file.getName());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.song_item, songs);
            setListAdapter(songList);


        }
    }
```

then this is the CategorySong class that extends the fragment to display the list

```
    public class CategorySongs extends ListFragment {
    MediaActivity mediaActivity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        container.removeAllViews();

        mediaActivity = new MediaActivity();
        mediaActivity.updateMusic();
        mediaActivity.buttons();

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_media, container, false);


    }


}
```

But I just receive this error

```
07-13 20:54:26.701    7281-7281/com.example.mason.mediaplayer E/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present 07-13 20:54:26.711    7281-7281/com.example.mason.mediaplayer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mason.mediaplayer, PID: 7281
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
        at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5259)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
        at com.example.mason.mediaplayer.MediaActivity.updateMusic(MediaActivity.java:287)
        at com.example.mason.mediaplayer.CategorySongs.onCreateView(CategorySongs.java:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Android OS first instantiates the Activity, then it does some additional setup to provide the base Context and environment information for that Activity. These are necessary to access system services like the `LayoutInflater`, which is what the `ArrayAdapter` is trying to access during its construction.

Your code includes assignments to member variables in the same line that you declare them. These assignments occur at construction (they may as well be inside your Activity's constructor), which is before the OS has completed setup of the Activity. You need to move those assignments into `onCreate()` or later.